# How to refresh list view after adding the contact from contact intent?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, refresh

I have an activity in which I am showing the contacts from phone in a list view. Now I have added function of adding the new contact by calling the contact intent to add a new contact. This is done nicely.

But when I get return to the activity after adding the contact I can not see the latest added contact.

I tried to refresh the list view by calling invalidate() also on adapter I tried by calling invalidate() onResume method.

But I can not get the result. I also tried to call the add intent with startActivityForResult and get the contacts in the onActivityResult() but that also failed.

Don't know what's going  wrong. Please help.

Activity:

```
public class ContactList extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<contact> contact_list = null;
    private contactAdapter mContactAdapter = null;

    private ArrayList<contact> items;
    private ArrayList<contact> selectedContacts;
    boolean[] isChecked;
    Cursor mCursor;
    ListView lv;
    public int RQS_PICK_CONTACT = 1,RQS_ADD_CONTACT = 2;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedItemsPositions;
    private ImageView done,back;
    private boolean mContactListActivity;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_list);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("");
        TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

        toolbarTitle.setText("Select Contacts");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        done = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.done);

        back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        contact_list = new ArrayList<contact>();

        selectedContacts = new ArrayList<contact>();

     //   selectedItemsPositions = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        showContacts();

        //getContacts();


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent,RQS_ADD_CONTACT);


            }
        });


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void getContacts() {


        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };


       mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "upper("+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            contact contact = new contact();

            String contactId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            contact.setContactid(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
            contact.setContactName(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            contact_list.add(contact);
        }
        isChecked = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < isChecked.length; i++) {
            isChecked[i] = false;
        }


        this.mContactAdapter = new contactAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, contact_list);
        lv.setAdapter(this.mContactAdapter);
        mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     //   mCursor.close();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RQS_PICK_CONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                getContacts();

            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                getContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void showContacts()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        }

        else {

            getContacts();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {

        super.onResume();

        mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        //finish();
        //startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    inside yourr onResume() add this
   if (listvew!= null) {
    listvew.invalidateViews();
}
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: try this  listview.invalidateViews();  @user6265109

Comment: dose not help. :-( @muruga5000

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside `onResume()`

```
if(adapter!= null){
    listvew.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```